# "can't optimize a non-leaf Tensor" on torch Parameter

Tags: pytorch

I'm getting "can't optimize a non-leaf Tensor" on this bit of code

```
self.W_ch1 = nn.Parameter(
            torch.rand(encoder_feature_dim, encoder_feature_dim), requires_grad=True
        ).to(self.device)
self.W_ch1_optimizer = torch.optim.Adam([self.W_ch1], lr=encoder_lr)
```

Don't know why it's happening that should be the leaf tensor, because it has no children connected to it. It's just a `torch.rand` inside a `nn.Parameter` variable. It throws the error at the initialization of `self.w_ch1_optmizer`

[image]

Comment: Can you show the code where you are performing inference and backpropagation?

Comment: @Ivan actually it throws that error at the optimizer initialization. Not sure why.

Comment: The below code works for me. So I don't think there is a problem with this code.
```
W_ch1 = nn.Parameter(torch.rand(10,10), requires_grad=True) 
W_ch1_optimizer = torch.optim.Adam([W_ch1], lr=1e-3)      
```

Comment: @UmangGupta that's so weird. I added a screen shot to show that's exactly where it's breaking.

Comment: There may be something else wrong with your code that may be causing this to break. Can you run the two-line code that I wrote in the previous comment and check if you get the error? Also, which torch version?

Comment: @UmangGupta ran it. It does work. For whatever reason my code started working after I removed `.to(device)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why it throws an error is that [`torch.Tensor.cuda`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html#torch.nn.Module.to) has the effect of creating a reference for transferring the data doing so by registering a new node in the graph. In other words your parameter module `W_ch1` is no longer a leaf node since you already have this "computation" tree:

```
nn.Parameter -> cuda:parameter = W_ch1
```

You can compare the following two results:

```
>>> p = nn.Parameter(torch.rand(1)).cuda()
>>> p.is_leaf
False
```

What you need to be doing is first instantiate your modules, and define your optimizer(s). Only then can you transfer them to the desired device. Not before:

```
>>> p = nn.Parameter(torch.rand(1))
>>> optimizer = optim.Adam([p], lr=lr)
```

Then you can transfer everything:

```
>>> p.cuda()
>>> optimizer.cuda()
```